# How long should it take to get a Russian passport?

Tags: passports, russia, russian-citizens, embassies, consulates

How long does it take to get a Russian passport if you're travelling or living abroad?

Answer (score 3):

According to federal law, a passport should be issued within 3 months of the date of application.

(note that the date quotes below are not the edition date of the law, but rather the registration date, as some sources put it -- something akin to the date of the first passage of the given law, which then can get amended multiple times, still bearing the original date for reference purposes)

An excerpt from [Федеральный закон № 114-ФЗ от 15 августа 1996 г.](http://www.fms.gov.ru/documentation/860/details/50440/2/)

> Срок оформления паспорта дипломатическим представительством или консульским учреждением Российской Федерации не должен превышать три месяца со дня подачи заявления о выдаче паспорта, за исключением случаев подачи заявления о выдаче паспорта в форме электронного документа с использованием информационно-телекоммуникационных сетей общего пользования, в том числе сети Интернет, включая единый портал государственных и муниципальных услуг.
>
> (часть введена Федеральным законом от 24.06.1999 N 118-ФЗ, в ред. Федеральных законов от 21.12.2009 N 337-ФЗ, от 27.07.2010 N 227-ФЗ)

---

Additionally, according to the orders from the Ministry of Foreign Affairs of the Russian Federation, there are strict limits on the time during which you have to wait in queue -- no more than 15 minutes, and during which your document packet should be processed -- no more than 30 minutes.

For the 5-year old-style laminated passport, [МИД РФ Приказ от 28 июня 2012 г. № 10303](http://www.kdmid.ru/cd.aspx?lst=normdocs_wiki&it=/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%20%D0%9C%D0%98%D0%94%20%D0%A0%D0%A4%20%D0%BE%D1%82%2028.06.2012%20N%2010303.aspx)

> **Максимальный срок ожидания в очереди при подаче запроса о предоставлении государственной услуги и при получении результата государственной услуги**
>
> 28. Максимальный срок ожидания в очереди не должен превышать:
>
>     - 15 минут - при подаче документов, необходимых для предоставления государственной услуги;
>         (в ред. Приказа МИД России от 24.06.2014 N 10302)
>     - 15 минут - при получении результата предоставления государственной услуги.
>         (в ред. Приказа МИД России от 24.06.2014 N 10302)
>
> **Срок и порядок регистрации запроса заявителя о предоставлении государственной услуги**
>
> 29. Регистрация заявления производится в порядке, предусмотренном пунктом 43 настоящего Регламента, и осуществляется в срок, не превышающий 30 минут с момента подачи заявителем всех надлежащим образом оформленных документов и фотографий, необходимых для предоставления государственной услуги.

For the 10-year new-style biometric passport [МИД РФ Приказ от 19 марта 2014 г. № 3744](http://www.mid.ru/bdomp/legislation.nsf/749680bd9e97b5ebc3257939004fc5f5/d60cda87f5aa1cd544257d2e0034cc40!OpenDocument)

> **Максимальный срок ожидания в очереди при подаче запроса о предоставлении государственной услуги и при получении результата государственной услуги**
>
> 28. Максимальный срок ожидания в очереди не превышает:
>
>     - 15 минут - при подаче документов, необходимых для предоставления государственной услуги;
>     - 15 минут - при получении результата государственной услуги.
>
> **Срок и порядок регистрации запроса заявителя о предоставлении государственной услуги**
>
> 29. Регистрация заявления производится в порядке, предусмотренном пунктом 41 настоящего Регламента, и осуществляется в срок, не превышающий 30 минут с момента подачи заявителем всех надлежащим образом оформленных документов и фотографий, необходимых для предоставления государственной услуги.

---

The above would suggest that the limits are rather strict and consumer friendly.

However, in practice, consulates seem to have found a different interpretation -- some require appointments, with wait times often exceeding multiple months in some jurisdictions, which definitely appears to be in violation of the spirit of the law, but seems to be getting under the radar due to their given interpretation of appointments not being explicitly regulated (and, perhaps, the populace being content with the mandatory appointment system and clueless on the protections and guarantees provided by the laws).

Comment: +1, I am grateful for your digging out the legislation.  Are these 15 minute  limits actually observed in Moscow/Peter? And when does the 15 minutes start?

Comment: @GayotFow, I have no idea, but failing to observe the limits entitles you to file a grievance; e.g. from the biometric regulations, ` 90. Заявитель может обратиться с жалобой, в том числе в следующих случаях:` ` нарушение срока регистрации заявления заявителя о предоставлении государственной услуги;` ` нарушение срока предоставления государственной услуги;` (somehow the queue wait time doesn't appear to be enumerated explicitly, but this list is not meant to be exhaustive)

Comment: @GayotFow, also, ` 100. В случае установления в ходе или по результатам рассмотрения жалобы признаков состава административного правонарушения, предусмотренного статьей 5.63 Кодекса Российской Федерации об административных правонарушениях, или признаков состава преступления должностное лицо, уполномоченное на рассмотрение жалоб, незамедлительно направляет соответствующие материалы в органы прокуратуры.` and ` 101. Возможность приостановления рассмотрения жалобы законодательством Российской Федерации не предусмотрена.`

Comment: and the time to get a response is actually 15 work days, not 30 days, as my own message to MID and KDMID has apparently been estimated for: `98. Жалоба, поступившая в МИД России, Представительство или загранучреждение, подлежит регистрации не позднее следующего рабочего дня со дня ее поступления. Жалоба рассматривается в течение 15 рабочих дней со дня ее регистрации.`

Comment: thanks for the head's up...  And подумала и сделала выводы.

Comment: These time limits are about the procedure of gathering the documents, not the passport issuance

Comment: @VMAtm, I don't really understand what your comment is about, or why someone downvoted this answer recently; the law is pretty clear that passport must be issued within 3 mo, has nothing to do with gathering the documents.

Comment: Downvote isn't my.