# What's the difference in regulations for 5-year vs. 10-year passport in Russia?

Tags: passports, russia, russian-citizens

What is the difference in the regulations for a 5-year old-style laminated passport, vs. 10-year new-style biometric one?

For example, as per [How long should it take to get a Russian passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46679/how-long-should-it-take-to-get-a-russian-passport), the regulations that establish both, seem to be separate documents, but with largely identical paragraphs, but with different enumeration of each point within each section as they go further down the line.

Additionally, it seems like one is only available from kdmid.ru, whereas the other only from mid.ru, both in slightly different formats, making it complicated to do the comparison for the nuanced differences.

---

## 5-year old-style laminated passport

[**МИД РФ Приказ от 28 июня 2012 г. № 10303**](http://www.kdmid.ru/cd.aspx?lst=normdocs_wiki&it=/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%20%D0%9C%D0%98%D0%94%20%D0%A0%D0%A4%20%D0%BE%D1%82%2028.06.2012%20N%2010303.aspx)

---

## 10-year new-style biometric passport

[**МИД РФ Приказ от 19 марта 2014 г. № 3744**](http://www.mid.ru/bdomp/legislation.nsf/749680bd9e97b5ebc3257939004fc5f5/d60cda87f5aa1cd544257d2e0034cc40!OpenDocument)

Comment: It seems like they're both referenced here, but one is an inline HTML, and the older one is a `.doc` --- http://www.mid.ru/bdomp/legislation.nsf/reglaments

Comment: also, found the kdmid link for the 10-year one: http://www.kdmid.ru/cd.aspx?lst=normdocs_wiki&it=/Administrativnyy%20reglament%2019.03.2014%20%E2%84%963744.aspx

Comment: btw, the versions on kdmid.ru don't show any of the attachments in line, so, the mid.ru 10-year version is the most complete html version, it seems

Answer (score 2):

First of all, these two types of passport all equal for the person that owns them - they are totally acceptable all across the world. But for the new-style biometric passport there is an opportunity to add some bio-parameter to the chip of the passport. This service isn't required, and still being in test period, but for some countries it can save a lot of time for now.

Second, as you've noticed, there are a lot of repeating paragraphs, as the passport are equal in their needs, they are equal in procedure to get them:

- Each type can be got in a period from 1 to 3 month, depending on circumstances
- Each type can be got by the web-site http://gosuslugi.ru, which provides a solution for a lot of bureaucratic procedures like passport gain, customs interaction, and so on.
- Each type has equal sequence to get them: from getting the allowance to getting the passport

But the main difference between them is that for getting the bio-passport you have to get to the regulator for making picture of yourself (as it's being done with some additional biometrical filters) comparing with the old-style passport which can be done for a child less than 14 years **without child being present** in regulator's office.

Another easy to find difference is the price:

- 5-year passport will be `1000 RUR / 300 RUR` for a child
- Outside the country it will be `30 USD / 10 USD` for a child
- 10-year passport will be `2500 RUR / 1200 RUR` for a child
- Outside the country it will be `80 USD / 40 USD` for a child

May be there are some other differences which can be found with detailed analysis of the texts you've linked but I think they matter only for a special cases.

If you can clarify what exactly you are concerned with, I'll try to investigate more.

Comment: good answer, thanks!  mostly interested in the procedural differences about getting one etc.  it's a good point that one doesn't require photographs, although i think the regulations still seem to suggest that a photograph is nonetheless required

Comment: Didn't understand the second part of your comment. I meant that you can create a passport for your child less than 14-years-old without his coming to the regulator's office. So, you provide all documents for them, and got the child passport by yourself. For bio-metric passport you have to bring the child to the office no matter how old they are.

Comment: What I meant is, for the biometric passport, you don't have to produce the photographs yourself, and all photographing is done at the office; however, i think regulations still appear to suggest that a photograph of the applicant by the applicant is also needed as part of the application...

Comment: Thats not actually true about no need in photos - they still be needed for an questionarie you have to fill. THese photos will not appear in passport but only in your personal folder

Comment: yes, that's what the regulations say, but in practice it seems like they don't require it anymore, at least, not in the consulates in the US

Comment: Good for you. Here in Russia we still have to provide it.