# Is it possible to apply for Russian passport by mail/internet in North America?

Tags: passports, russian-citizens, consulates

There is a limited number of Russian consulates across the vast territory of North America, and it would be quite inconvenient to have to attend one of them in person for passport renewal, especially since at least some of them appear to require lengthy prior appointments.

Is there perhaps any way to apply for a Russian passport by mail or over the internet, when abroad?

I recall seeing some info on the SF web-site that mail applications were discontinued (this info has since been removed, it appears), is there any information why and when it was discontinued?

It seems like the [present regulations](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46809/whats-the-difference-in-regulations-for-5-year-vs-10-year-passport-in-russia) might require in-person appearance, but it's somewhat difficult to track when such regulations were introduced and what were the prior ones.

Does federal law cover this at all?

It seems like [Федеральный закон № 114-ФЗ от 15 августа 1996 г.](http://www.fms.gov.ru/documentation/860/details/50440/2/) says the following:

> Паспорт оформляется гражданину Российской Федерации по его письменному заявлению о выдаче паспорта, поданному лично, через его законного представителя или в форме электронного документа с использованием информационно-телекоммуникационных сетей общего пользования, в том числе сети Интернет, включая единый портал государственных и муниципальных услуг

Is there any way to construe USPS or FedEx/UPS as one's legal representative?  Or how does one make the whole application through the internet and/or mail?

Are there perhaps any other developments for a more speedy passport issuance than the personal attendance plus the [three months for processing](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46679/how-long-should-it-take-to-get-a-russian-passport)?

Comment: North America covers Canada and Mexico.  Is this for US only?

Comment: I'm presently in the US, but plan to go to Canada for the summer (have to do land crossing, not having a passport!).

Comment: The regulations and actual processing times may vary from country to country.  Can you narrow this down?

Comment: Could you please translate, or at least paraphrase the gist, of that Russian block quote?

Comment: I believe you still need a passport to enter Canada by land, and to return to the US afterward.

Comment: @NateEldredge A green card is sufficient to enter Canada by land. Also an EDL will do. Not sure about returning to US, probably more strict. See http://www.dhs.gov/western-hemisphere-travel-initiative and http://www.getyouhome.gov/html/eng_map.html

Comment: @Calchas: Hmm, http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?q=593&t=16 says you need a passport with a green card.  The first link you give doesn't seem to address this question and the second site is apparently down.  Also, I believe US EDLs are only available to US citizens, so that wouldn't help the OP.

Comment: @NateEldredge I don't think that's right; see http://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/publications/pub/bsf5023-eng.html#s2x5. "Permanent residents of the United States may travel to Canada from the United States or Saint-Pierre and Miquelon without passports, travel documents or visas provided they produce satisfactory evidence of their identity and status."

Comment: @Calchas: Thanks, that does seem to be definitive.

Comment: You need to apply in person. If YOU live far they can mail you a passport by mail instead picking it up in person. But you would need to pay for your postage package stamp

Answer (score 5):

Consulates and Embassy in the USA have required in person visit for renewal and pickup of the Russian passport.  Spoke with the consulate in Seattle today and apparently there is some legislation that has passed but not yet effective, that will enable some passport services to take place by mail in the future.  He had no information on effective date.

Comment: do you have any details on this legislation?  i've read a comment on the google plus reviews of the SF consulate that you can apply by mail through a new order by Putin, but I haven't found the actual law.  I'm really interested in reading the actual law etc.  if anyone knows a reference, please kindly share.