# Can you apply for a new Russian passport at any time?

Tags: passports, russia, russian-citizens

I recall that supposedly you could only apply for a new Russian passport when your existing one was about to expire within the next 6 months.

However, currently, I couldn't find anything to that effect in the official [laws](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46679/how-long-should-it-take-to-get-a-russian-passport) and [regulations](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46809/whats-the-difference-in-regulations-for-5-year-vs-10-year-passport-in-russia) (but, then again, maybe I just missed it).

Is there anything to this effect, or is it more of a suggestion to make more use of the full term of one's existing passport prior to receiving a new one?  Or perhaps the 6-month restriction is a thing of the past?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR - You can renew the passport whenever you like.

In 2011 I held a 5-year passport that was due to expire in -- IIRC -- 2013. I was still enrolled at university at the time, which made me temporarily exempt from military service.

Since males of the appropriate age need approval (a specific form) from the military commissariat for an international passport, and as I had a PhD position lined up abroad, I figured it would be easier to renew my passport while I was still exempt from military service, rather than having to face the hassle of doing this in the middle of my PhD program, no longer having the relevant exemption.

To answer the question, **I had zero problems getting a new passport, valid for 10 years, while there was still 2 years left on my old one.** The lady at the issuing office was a bit surprised, but I simply told her, that I've got a position abroad and would like to avoid the inconvenience of renewing a passport from abroad.

Comment: cool, thanks for letting us know!  i'll accept this answer, as it's been a while i've asked this!

Comment: @cnst Thanks! As with many things in the fascinating Russian bureaucracy, "Your Mileage May Vary". A backup plan could be to fold the old passport in half and replace it as "damaged", though you'd have to pay an administrative fine for that (of the order of 2-3k roubles, I believe).

Comment: btw, if you find the question useful, don't forget to upvote, too. ;)  oh, and why would you have to pay an administrative fine?  do you have a source for that?  i've never seen it in the pricing list before; what you're talking about sounds just like the normal passport fee of a new passport.

Comment: @cnst I may be confusing this with the fine for damaging the internal passport, I'd have to double check that.

Comment: There is a fine for not having identifying documents; it's 2k to 3k RUB in Russia, and 3k to 5k in Moscow and SPb.  *КоАП РФ, Статья 19.15*

Comment: @cnst this particular fine is irrelevant in this case

Comment: @cnst I couldn't quickly find sources for the travel passport, but certainly the tariff for replacing a damaged internal passport is higher, than a simple replacement: Государственная пошлина за выдачу паспорта гражданина РФ взамен утраченного или пришедшего в негодность—1500 руб. [Source](https://гувм.мвд.рф/services/payment)

Answer (score 5):

This is only a recommendation from the consulates, as the time deadlines for a new passport creation are up to **3 months**, so if you want to get a new passport when your old one is about to expire in 2 months, you could get into to situation when you have no valid passport.

The only restriction is that you can't get a new passport **without invalidation the old one** ([Federal Law # 114](http://www.rg.ru/1996/08/22/vjezd-vyezd-dok.html) in Russian), with only one exclusion: if you regulary go out of the country (you have stamps in your passport for **3 consecutive months**), you can create another one, but **the expiry date for such passport will be equal to expiry date of the first one**.

**Update:**
About the **three consecutive months** rule:
Quote from law:

> В случае, если деятельность гражданина Российской Федерации связана с
>   **регулярными (не реже чем один раз в течение месяца) выездами** за
>   пределы территории Российской Федерации, а данный гражданин **не имеет
>   права на получение дипломатического или служебного паспорта**, ему **по
>   ходатайству организации, направляющей его за пределы территории
>   Российской Федерации**, может быть оформлен и выдан второй паспорт, при
>   этом во втором паспорте **днем окончания срока действия паспорта
>   указывается день окончания срока действия ранее выданного паспорта**.

So you need three points to get the second one passport without invalidating the first one:

- You can't get a diplomatic or working passport
- You regularly passed through the customs. This can be only one way approved: no less than 3 last consecutive months you've already gone through customs (say, one time is a fortuity, two times are coincidence, three times - are you kidding me?).
- You have a job which is related with trips, and your organization can create such request for you.

There are a lot of sites with detailed explanation, like this:
http://www.yfms-passport.ru/two_international_passport

**Note**: if you are saying that you lost your passport, it will be invalidated, and even if you find it later, it can't be validated back.

Comment: Do you know where the 3 consecutive month requirement comes from?  I've seen it before, but I couldn't find any law or regulation that mentions it.

Comment: For quotes on Russian law, I think you also have to quote the date of registration -- day, month, year -- since the numbers seem to repeat themselves each year (but then it's confusing why it seems custom to quote the whole date, instead of just the year!)

Comment: Updated the answer. The numbers of passport are different each time! This is exactly why the old one is invalidated!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to VMAtm's answer, for practical purposes, also consider the field on the passport application where you have to select whether it's your first passport, or whether you're getting it in exchange of a used/damaged/lost one.

> 9 Получение паспорта
>
> - Первичное
> - Взамен использованного
> - Взамен испорченного
> - Взамен утраченного

When picking up the new passport, if the old passport is otherwise valid, it'll be taken momentarily to have holes punched through it, and returned back to you.